# Sample different number of rows in a R loop

Tags: r

I'm trying to sample different number of rows of a dataframe in R. I would like to obtain this sample for N rows, which are share a given attribute (in my case, cell_id_25km) multiple times. Than based on each **sample** with N rows, I would like to apply a function (in other words: do something with it and save the results).

Here is the code I'm using without success:

An example of my dataframe (df):

```
cell_id_25km latitude longitude date_collected N_rec species id_species  

   101064  -23.625    30.125     1924-03-31  2142  sp.783          1           
   101064  -23.600    30.100     1982-01-24  2142  sp.783          1         
   101064  -23.625    30.125     1968-03-15  2142  sp.783          1           
   101064  -23.625    30.125     1918-02-28  2142  sp.783          1        
   101064  -23.625    30.125     1960-02-29  2142  sp.783          1         
   101064  -23.625    30.125     1958-01-13  2142  sp.783          1
```

The code I'm trying:

```
nrep<-100

cell=unique(df$cell_id_25km)

tt3<-c()

tt4<-c()

tt5<-c()

    for(j in 1:nrep){
      u[j]<- round(runif(1, min = 100, max = 1000), digits = 0)
      for (i in 1:length(cell)) {
        for (k in 1:length(u[j])){ 
          dat3 = df[df$cell_id_25km == cell[i], c("cell_id_25km", "id_species", "species")]
          tt4[[k]] <- sample_n(dat3, u[j], replace = FALSE)
          tt5[[k]]<- length(unique(tt4$species))}}}
```

I think I'm not saving the results of the loop correctly.

Comment: Where is the `uu2` coming from?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it. It is my dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is at this line: 
    `tt5[[k]] <- length(unique(tt4$species))`

Change it to this: 
    `tt5[[k]] <- length(unique(tt4[[k]]$species))`

For saving your results, I would make tt3, tt4, and tt5 lists. Then, change tt5 to include j, i, and k for saving results (otherwise you are rewriting results using just k).

Add these changes:

```
`tt3 <- list()
tt4 <- list()
tt5 <- list()
tt5[[paste(j, i, k, sep = " ")]] <- length(unique(tt4[[k]]$species))`
```

After your code, you can get all the results by using `do.call` (`do.call(rbind, tt5)`).

```
`nrep<-100

cell=unique(df$cell_id_25km)

tt3<-list()

tt4<-list()

tt5<-list()

u <- list()

for(j in 1:nrep){
  u[j]<- round(runif(1, min = 100, max = 1000), digits = 0)
  for (i in 1:length(cell)) {
    for (k in 1:length(u[j])){ 
      dat3 = df[df$cell_id_25km == cell[i], c("cell_id_25km", "id_species", "species")]
      tt4[[k]] <- sample_n(dat3, as.numeric(u[j]), replace = FALSE)
      tt5[[paste(j,i,k,sep=" ")]]<- length(unique(tt4[[k]]$species))}}}


do.call(rbind, tt5)`
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you! I can't see exactly how I should change tt5 to include j, i, and k to save the results. Could you provide an example of the code? Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer to show the changes I made in your code.